# Python library for read/write different ECG formats (MIT, SCP-ECG, HL7 aECG)

Tags: python, file, format

Does anybody know all-in-one Python library for read/write the most famous ECG(electrocardiogram) formats? For example: MIT, SCP-ECG, HL7 aECG. Or single functions will be enough

Comment: Remark: i know about WFDB library, but it supports MIT format only

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything similar and I think that it is rather hard to have something like that. I just read the ANSI/AAMI EC71:2001 specifications (for the SCP-ECG standard), it is a shame that the document is available only by payment (over 150 euros!), but it is also a nightmare of rules and algorythms. Just to cite some parts: compression using Huffman coding with pre-made or custom tables, sequences stored as absolute numbers or as "first differences" or "second differences", bimodal compression, etc. Another format I read about was the DICOM, it is another worst nightmare, if possible. So, just speaking about SCP-ECG only, it is rather simple to write a coder, but a very hard task to write a complete parser.
Anyway I wrote just a proof-of-concept Python script, to parse a simple SCP-ECG file and to produce a CSV, you can find it here: https://github.com/RigacciOrg/ecg-contec/tree/main/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the link is broken

Comment: Sorry @Krivenkoz, I fixed the link now.

Answer (score 0):

[WFDB's non-python version](https://www.physionet.org/content/wfdb/10.6.2/) can convert [SCP-ECG files](https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wag/parses-1.htm) (which are a nightmare to work with) directly from bash:

```sh
parsescp -o "${filename%.scp}" -w <$filename
```

For the rest (HL7, MIT, etc.) you can find different standalone libraries.

I know this is a rather old question and that my answer doesn't address the OP's question, as it's not a Python package, but this is one of the first results when googling and I think it's valuable to provide the possible solution using WFDB. In my case it has served its purpose:

[image]